# Jquery menu toggled logo opacity to zero

Tags: jquery

I want to just make the main logo `opacity 0` and the script i have here is only `fadeToggle` and the when I click it all content will go up.

```
<script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $('.menu-trigger').click(function(){
                $('.logosp').fadeToggle();
            });
        });
</script>
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use the .fadeTo() method.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$(".menu-trigger").click(function(){
$(".logosp").fadeTo(1000, 0.4);
});
});
```

Where the first parameter determining how long the animation will run and the second parameter is number between 0 and 1 denoting the target opacity.

Answer (score 2):

Then, instead of `fadeToggle`, you should do:

```
$('.logosp').css({opacity: 0});
```

**Edit** due user request:

Then you should change the opacity depending of the current value it has:

```
$('.logosp').css({opacity: $('.logosp').css('opacity') == 0 ? 1 : 0 })
```

If you don't care about the 'slot' the element let when it became invisible, then you should consider just doing:

```
$('.logosp').toggle(0);
```

Comment: I tried it but when I toogle it again the logo won't appear again